# Given an integer array, use recursion to find the array's approximate median value

Tags: java, recursion

I am given int array of varying lengths from 1 element ~ 100_000 elements.
  I need to find an approximate median value of the given int array.
    for example,

```
     given array of [4], median is 4 since there is only 1 element

     given array of [4,5], (4+5) / 2.0 = 4.5 is median.

     given array of [4,5,6],
        break array into 3 pieces [4][5][6]
        what is the middle value ? 5 = median.

     given array of [4,5,6,7],
        break array into 3 pieces [4][5,6][7]
        median of [4]   is 4
        median of [5,6] is 5.5
        median of [7]   is 7
          4 vs 5.5 vs 7 
            median of given array [4,5,6,7] is 5.5
```

With the given array, I am supposed to divide the array into three pieces(without creating new array or modifying the given array).

In dividing the given array into three pieces, these are three possibilities

```
      1. given array's length(6) % 3 = 0 
           (The case when a remainder is 0)
         given array   --> [2,3,5,3,1,4] 
         divide into 3 --> [2,3][5,3][1,4]
                         each pieces are length of n/3. In this particular case(n = 6), 6/3 = 2 = length of each piece.

      2. given array's length(10) % 3 = 1
           (The case when a remainder is 1)
         given array   --> [1,2,-20,-10,7,20,-3,100,6,92]
         divide into 3 --> [1,2,-20][-10,7,20,-3][100,6,92]
                          left and right side piece is length of n/3(10/3).
                          middle piece is n/3(10/3) rounded up

      3. given array's length(8) % 3 = 2
           (Last case when a remainder is 2)
         given array   -->  [1,2,10,7,20,-3,100,6]
         divide into 3 -->  [1,2,10][7,20][-3,100,6]
```

Implement the method public static double median3(int[] a) {}

This is a homework from the cs course intended to help student practice recursions. I am feeling baffled as I am not quite sure where I should begin if I were to use recursion. 
I can do simple recursions that I learned from the class such as fibbonacci sequence or factorial number. But this problem, I cannot seem to find the same pattern that I applied to the simpler recursion problems...

I would appreciate if you can set me off to some direction and give me any of your tips. 
Thank you.

Comment: Start by defining the "base case" of your method, for example if the array you get is empty, or if it has only one element, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably meant to handle 3 cases:

1. for length = 1 you take the element as that sub array's median
2. for length = 2 you calculate the median as the average of those 2 elements
3. for lengths >= 3 you split the array as per the rules you stated above and *then* apply the same method (i.e. those 3 cases) to the 2nd (center) array. You don't need to split the array, just keep track of the indices which mark the first elements of the 2nd and 3rd sub arrays.

Example:

Let's start with the array `[1,2,-20,-10,7,20,-3,100,6,92]`. Its length is >= 3 so you split it to `[1,2,-20][-10,7,20,-3][100,6,92]`,

Now you recursively handle the center array `[-10,7,20,-3]`. Its length is still >3 so you split again and get `[-10[[7,20][-3]`.

The "new" center array is `[7,20]` and because the length is 2 you calculate the median as `(7+20)/2.0 = 13.5`.